# window.location.replace not working with some urls

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a JavaScript redirect.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
window.location.replace('https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/jump/N5371.1920006AAPLUS/B10640187.141970298;sz=1x1;ord=[timestamp]?')
```

This returns `undefined` and does nothing.

However, in the exact same context

```
window.location.replace('https://ad.doubleclick.net');
```

works just fine. What gives?

Sorry for the ad tag; it's the only URL I've found that doesn't work so far.

Comment: It's probably returning a 204. What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: Good thought, but it's actually returning a 302.

Comment: Oh, but the 302 location is returning a 204.

Comment: It happens because `The requested page has moved temporarily to a new URL` source:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp

Comment: yousoff that's not an issue. The issue was the location redirected to served a 204. 302s are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if your URL serves `204 No Content` (which tells the browser to do nothing).

Comment: I'm unclear. So his first url above serves no content? Do you mean the page is vacant, not there? Certainly it looks like content would be there. I'm happening the same and my url points to a real page of content. :(

Comment: actually, to my surprise, nothing!
Now after more research my window.locatiion.replace(url) is with url = '/newpage'. I think that my error may be that it should be simply 'newpage'.

Answer (score -2):

That's because your `url` trails is not valid. If you try it with just 'https://ad.doubleclick.net' it works fine.